# How to count how many times a loop condition is checked

Tags: java

I am working on a program that would count how many statements are executed in an algorithm. I am not able to count when the inside loop condition turns to false.

Currently, I am working on a program that counts the number of executed statements in a bubble sort algorithm. Here is my current method:

```
public static Stats bubbleSort(List<String> names) {
    Stats stats = new Stats();
    for (int x = 0; x < names.size() - 1; x++) {
        for (int y = x + 1; y < names.size(); y++) {
            if (names.get(x).compareTo(names.get(y)) > 0) {
                String temp = names.get(x);
                names.set(x, names.get(y));
                names.set(y, temp);
                stats.inLineStatements += 3;
            }
            stats.ifStatements += 1;
            stats.updateExpressionStatements += 1;
            stats.conditionStatements += 1;
        }
        stats.updateExpressionStatements += 1;
        stats.conditionStatements += 1;
    }
    stats.conditionStatements += 1;
    stats.initializationExpressionStatements += 2;
    return stats;
}
```

I made a Stats class containing the different statements to be counted. The problem is when I am testing it with a List composed of three elements, the loop condition statements are only 6 in the best case scenario. Although, when I manually count it should be 8. What could be causing this? I am suspecting that it has something to do with the inner loop not being counted although I am not quite sure.

Here is an example of a sample run:

```
Bubble Sort: 
Initialization Statements (For Loop):   2
Loop Condition Statements:  6
If Statements:  3
In Line Statements:     0
Update Expression Statements (For Loop):    5
Total Statements:   16
```

Comment: Just move the loop counter inside the inner `for`.

Comment: The manual count is off. `y = x + 1` gives 3 (y) + 2 (x) + 1 (x).

Comment: I am not saying that it is pointless what you are doing, but in my experience it is often better to just compute an estimate using big O notation rather than putting in the work to actually count the executions, it is all in the code. The only reason I can think of to need to count the executions specifically is for embedded systems to squeeze every bit of performance out. However, then you would be using C or Rust, certainly not Java.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for, but I am guessing you need to add an `else` to the `if` to update stats when the `if` condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I am working on a program that would count how many statements are executed in an algorithm. I am not able to count when the inside loop condition turns to false. ..."*

*Java* defines a *statement* as the following.

*[Expressions, Statements, and Blocks (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)*.

> *"Statements are roughly equivalent to sentences in natural languages. A statement forms a complete unit of execution. The following types of expressions can be made into a statement by terminating the expression with a semicolon (;).*
>
> - *Assignment expressions*
> - *Any use of ++ or --*
> - *Method invocations*
> - *Object creation expressions*"

So, I would use the following for the *Stats* class.

```java
class Stats {
    int assignments, unaryOps, calls, newObjects;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return
              "assignments=%,d%n".formatted(assignments)
            + "unaryOps=%,d%n".formatted(unaryOps)
            + "calls=%,d%n".formatted(calls)
            + "newObjects=%,d".formatted(newObjects);
    }
}
```

And, for the procedure, I'd count the values like this.

```java
public static Stats bubbleSort(List<String> names) {
    Stats stats = new Stats();
    stats.assignments++;
    stats.newObjects++;
    String temp;
    for (int x = 0; x < names.size() - 1; x++) {
        stats.calls++;
        stats.unaryOps++;
        for (int y = x + 1; y < names.size(); y++) {
            stats.calls++;
            stats.unaryOps++;
            if (names.get(x).compareTo(names.get(y)) > 0) {
                stats.calls += 3;
                temp = names.get(x);
                stats.assignments++;
                stats.calls++;
                names.set(x, names.get(y));
                names.set(y, temp);
                stats.calls += 3;
            }
        }
        stats.assignments++;
        stats.calls++;
        stats.unaryOps++;
    }
    stats.assignments++;
    stats.calls++;
    stats.unaryOps++;
    return stats;
}
```

Here is the output for a 3 item list, *"a", "b", "c"*, once forward and once backward.

```java
assignments=4
unaryOps=8
calls=8
newObjects=1

assignments=7
unaryOps=8
calls=29
newObjects=1
```

> *"...  The problem is when I am testing it with a List composed of three elements, the loop condition statements are only 6 in the best case scenario. Although, when I manually count it should be 8. What could be causing this? ..."*

You'll need to increment *stats.conditionStatements* after the *for-loop*, additionally.
Also, I don't think you're counting the *if* statement, which is a *conditional-statement*.

```java
for (int x = 0; x < names.size() - 1; x++) {
    for (int y = x + 1; y < names.size(); y++) {
        if (names.get(x).compareTo(names.get(y)) > 0) {
        }
        stats.conditionStatements += 2;
    }
    stats.conditionStatements += 2;
}
stats.conditionStatements += 1;
```

As a solution, to visualize the *loop* execution, and the state of the variables, just print their values.
I typically indent the output for each *scope*.

```java
public static Stats bubbleSort(List<String> names) {
    out.printf("names = %,d, %s%n", names.size(), names);
 // Stats stats = new Stats();
    String temp;
    int x, y;
    for (x = 0; x < names.size() - 1; x++) {
        out.printf("  x = %,d%n", x);
        for (y = x + 1; y < names.size(); y++) {
            out.printf("    y = %,d%n", y);
            out.printf("    x - y = %,d%n", names.get(x).compareTo(names.get(y)));
            if (names.get(x).compareTo(names.get(y)) > 0) {
                temp = names.get(x);
                out.printf("      temp = '%s'%n", temp);
                names.set(x, names.get(y));
                names.set(y, temp);
                out.printf("      swapped %,d and %,d%n", x, y);
            }
        }
        out.printf("  y = %,d%n", y);
    }
    out.printf("x = %,d%n", x);
    return null;
}
```

Here is the output for *a, b, c*.

```
names = 3, [a, b, c]
  x = 0
    y = 1
    x - y = -1
    y = 2
    x - y = -2
  y = 3
  x = 1
    y = 2
    x - y = -1
  y = 3
x = 2
```

Here is *c, b, a*.

```
names = 3, [c, b, a]
  x = 0
    y = 1
    x - y = 1
      temp = 'c'
      swapped 0 and 1
    y = 2
    x - y = 1
      temp = 'b'
      swapped 0 and 2
  y = 3
  x = 1
    y = 2
    x - y = 1
      temp = 'c'
      swapped 1 and 2
  y = 3
x = 2
```

And, here is a random sequence.

```
names = 10, [i, p, z, p, w, p, a, x, r, m]
  x = 0
    y = 1
    x - y = -7
    y = 2
    x - y = -17
    y = 3
    x - y = -7
    y = 4
    x - y = -14
    y = 5
    x - y = -7
    y = 6
    x - y = 8
      temp = 'i'
      swapped 0 and 6
    y = 7
    x - y = -23
    y = 8
    x - y = -17
    y = 9
    x - y = -12
  y = 10
  x = 1
    y = 2
    x - y = -10
    y = 3
    x - y = 0
    y = 4
    x - y = -7
    y = 5
    x - y = 0
    y = 6
    x - y = 7
      temp = 'p'
      swapped 1 and 6
    y = 7
    x - y = -15
    y = 8
    x - y = -9
    y = 9
    x - y = -4
  y = 10
  x = 2
    y = 3
    x - y = 10
      temp = 'z'
      swapped 2 and 3
    y = 4
    x - y = -7
    y = 5
    x - y = 0
    y = 6
    x - y = 0
    y = 7
    x - y = -8
    y = 8
    x - y = -2
    y = 9
    x - y = 3
      temp = 'p'
      swapped 2 and 9
  y = 10
  x = 3
    y = 4
    x - y = 3
      temp = 'z'
      swapped 3 and 4
    y = 5
    x - y = 7
      temp = 'w'
      swapped 3 and 5
    y = 6
    x - y = 0
    y = 7
    x - y = -8
    y = 8
    x - y = -2
    y = 9
    x - y = 0
  y = 10
  x = 4
    y = 5
    x - y = 3
      temp = 'z'
      swapped 4 and 5
    y = 6
    x - y = 7
      temp = 'w'
      swapped 4 and 6
    y = 7
    x - y = -8
    y = 8
    x - y = -2
    y = 9
    x - y = 0
  y = 10
  x = 5
    y = 6
    x - y = 3
      temp = 'z'
      swapped 5 and 6
    y = 7
    x - y = -1
    y = 8
    x - y = 5
      temp = 'w'
      swapped 5 and 8
    y = 9
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'r'
      swapped 5 and 9
  y = 10
  x = 6
    y = 7
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'z'
      swapped 6 and 7
    y = 8
    x - y = 1
      temp = 'x'
      swapped 6 and 8
    y = 9
    x - y = 5
      temp = 'w'
      swapped 6 and 9
  y = 10
  x = 7
    y = 8
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'z'
      swapped 7 and 8
    y = 9
    x - y = 1
      temp = 'x'
      swapped 7 and 9
  y = 10
  x = 8
    y = 9
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'z'
      swapped 8 and 9
  y = 10
x = 9
```

As a final example, here are both codes merged.

```java
public static Stats bubbleSort(List<String> names) {
    out.printf("names = %,d, %s%n", names.size(), names);
    Stats stats = new Stats();
    stats.assignments++;
    stats.newObjects++;
    out.printf("stats = %n%s", stats.toString().indent(2));
    String temp = null;
    out.println("temp = " + temp);
    int x, y;
    for (x = 0; x < names.size() - 1; x++) {
        stats.calls++;
        stats.unaryOps++;
        out.printf("  x = %,d%n", x);
        for (y = x + 1; y < names.size(); y++) {
            stats.calls++;
            stats.unaryOps++;
            out.printf("    y = %,d%n", y);
            out.printf("    x - y = %,d%n", names.get(x).compareTo(names.get(y)));
            if (names.get(x).compareTo(names.get(y)) > 0) {
                stats.calls += 3;
                temp = names.get(x);
                stats.calls++;
                out.printf("      temp = '%s'%n", temp);
                names.set(x, names.get(y));
                names.set(y, temp);
                stats.calls += 3;
                out.printf("      swapped %,d and %,d%n", x, y);
            }
        }
        stats.assignments++;
        stats.calls++;
        stats.unaryOps++;
        out.println("  y = " + y);
    }
    stats.assignments++;
    stats.calls++;
    stats.unaryOps++;
    out.println("x = " + x);
    out.printf("stats = %n%s", stats.toString().indent(2));
    return null;
}
```

And, here is the output for the same lists.

```
names = 3, [a, b, c]
stats = 
  assignments=1
  unaryOps=0
  calls=0
  newObjects=1
temp = null
  x = 0
    y = 1
    x - y = -1
    y = 2
    x - y = -2
  y = 3
  x = 1
    y = 2
    x - y = -1
  y = 3
x = 2
stats = 
  assignments=4
  unaryOps=8
  calls=8
  newObjects=1

names = 3, [c, b, a]
stats = 
  assignments=1
  unaryOps=0
  calls=0
  newObjects=1
temp = null
  x = 0
    y = 1
    x - y = 1
      temp = 'c'
      swapped 0 and 1
    y = 2
    x - y = 1
      temp = 'b'
      swapped 0 and 2
  y = 3
  x = 1
    y = 2
    x - y = 1
      temp = 'c'
      swapped 1 and 2
  y = 3
x = 2
stats = 
  assignments=4
  unaryOps=8
  calls=29
  newObjects=1

names = 10, [d, w, n, u, y, d, s, f, i, s]
stats = 
  assignments=1
  unaryOps=0
  calls=0
  newObjects=1
temp = null
  x = 0
    y = 1
    x - y = -19
    y = 2
    x - y = -10
    y = 3
    x - y = -17
    y = 4
    x - y = -21
    y = 5
    x - y = 0
    y = 6
    x - y = -15
    y = 7
    x - y = -2
    y = 8
    x - y = -5
    y = 9
    x - y = -15
  y = 10
  x = 1
    y = 2
    x - y = 9
      temp = 'w'
      swapped 1 and 2
    y = 3
    x - y = -7
    y = 4
    x - y = -11
    y = 5
    x - y = 10
      temp = 'n'
      swapped 1 and 5
    y = 6
    x - y = -15
    y = 7
    x - y = -2
    y = 8
    x - y = -5
    y = 9
    x - y = -15
  y = 10
  x = 2
    y = 3
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'w'
      swapped 2 and 3
    y = 4
    x - y = -4
    y = 5
    x - y = 7
      temp = 'u'
      swapped 2 and 5
    y = 6
    x - y = -5
    y = 7
    x - y = 8
      temp = 'n'
      swapped 2 and 7
    y = 8
    x - y = -3
    y = 9
    x - y = -13
  y = 10
  x = 3
    y = 4
    x - y = -2
    y = 5
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'w'
      swapped 3 and 5
    y = 6
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'u'
      swapped 3 and 6
    y = 7
    x - y = 5
      temp = 's'
      swapped 3 and 7
    y = 8
    x - y = 5
      temp = 'n'
      swapped 3 and 8
    y = 9
    x - y = -10
  y = 10
  x = 4
    y = 5
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'y'
      swapped 4 and 5
    y = 6
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'w'
      swapped 4 and 6
    y = 7
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'u'
      swapped 4 and 7
    y = 8
    x - y = 5
      temp = 's'
      swapped 4 and 8
    y = 9
    x - y = -5
  y = 10
  x = 5
    y = 6
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'y'
      swapped 5 and 6
    y = 7
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'w'
      swapped 5 and 7
    y = 8
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'u'
      swapped 5 and 8
    y = 9
    x - y = 0
  y = 10
  x = 6
    y = 7
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'y'
      swapped 6 and 7
    y = 8
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'w'
      swapped 6 and 8
    y = 9
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'u'
      swapped 6 and 9
  y = 10
  x = 7
    y = 8
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'y'
      swapped 7 and 8
    y = 9
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'w'
      swapped 7 and 9
  y = 10
  x = 8
    y = 9
    x - y = 2
      temp = 'y'
      swapped 8 and 9
  y = 10
x = 9
stats = 
  assignments=11
  unaryOps=64
  calls=218
  newObjects=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct counting of the conditions:

```
for (int x = 0; x < names.size() - 1; x++) {
    for (int y = x + 1; y < names.size(); y++) {
        if (names.get(x).compareTo(names.get(y)) > 0) {
        }
        stats.conditionStatements += 1;
    }
    stats.conditionStatements += 2;
}
stats.conditionStatements += 1;
```

Within the inner loop, we count the true condition, so we increase the counter by one there. Outside of the inner cycle, but within the outer cycle, we count also the true condition of the outer cycle and the false condition that causes exit from the inner cycle. Therefore, the counter must be increased by two there. Finally, after the outer loop, we increase it by one again, because of the false condition only.